# Is it possible to replace NL join with HS join in sql

Tags: sql, db2, query-optimization

Hi am having a very big query comprises of two main table and 15 sub tables.

```
ie, Main table say table_a join with some other 10 tables.
and another main table sat table_b join with some other 5 tables.

Table_a contains - 314988 rows and 
Table_b contains - 710989 rows.
```

when we join i could find many NL Joins and HS joins.

intresting fact that all `HSjoin cost very less and NL join cost` very very high.

So is it possible to convert the joins from NL to HS Join.

Note : its all indexed.. there is no TBSCAN everything is IXSCAN.

Comment: What is your default optimization level?  Are your statistics up-to-date on all tables and indexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an optimization profile, where you will indicate to the optimizer which methods it should use to access the data for the given query.

Take a look at this tutorial from DeveloperWorks: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1202storedprocedure/index.html

Comment: Optimization profiles should be used VERY sparingly and only after exhausting all other possibilities.

Comment: Hi Pals, Thanks for the answer and guidance. just to put my question more precise, " i had a query been used in actuate e-Report designer and am executing its .rox file. the thing is in that i had a query as in the question, so is it possible to replace NL join with HS join with some changes in query alone? we execute this in actuate and will deploy the .rox in server console.. so is it possible to change by making changes in query?  TIA...

Comment: @Ian The question does not say how to improve a query, it just asks about how to change a join method. It is true that a query could be improved by rewriting it, changing the optimization level, and even the configuration in the machine, but that was not the question. The only way to change a join method in DB2 is with an optimization profile, the other options helps the optimizer but they don't assure the desired join method is used in all conditions.

Comment: @AngocA You are right – and you did answer the original question.  I only added my comment to offer some caution. Asking "how can I eliminate a certain type of join" as opposed to "how can I make my query work better" is a common mistake, as it assumes that the person asking the question knows that one join type will work better than another – in my experience this is RARELY the case. But, I'll grant that it's certainly possible that the OP had already done the analysis and determined that forcing a certain join type is the only solution.

Comment: @AProgrammer Lots of things affect the DB2 optimizer: the physical data model (tables, indexes), table statistics, physical properties of how the data has been stored (i.e. how well data within a table is clustered).  The way a query is written can also affect the query plan, although the internal query rewrite inside the DB2 optimizer has become so good that it's difficult to outsmart it by rewriting your queries).