# Can I use with(index(xxx)) in my SQL with DB2

Tags: sql, indexing, db2

I'm used to being able to tell my sql statement which index I'd like for it to use in MSSQL. But it seems like that doesn't work in DB2 the same way.

This statement works for me in MSSQL but not in Db2. :

```
SELECT ACT.COMPANY,ACT.ACCT_UNIT,ACT.ACTIVITY,ACT.ACTIVITY_GRP,ACT.ACCT_CATEGORY,ACT.TRAN_AMOUNT,ACT.DESCRIPTION as ACT_DESCRIPTION,
AP.VENDOR,AP.INVOICE,AP.PO_NUMBER,AC.DESCRIPTION as AC_DESCRIPTION
FROM
ACTRANS ACT WITH (INDEX(ATNSET12)),
APDISTRIB AP WITH (INDEX(APDSET9)), 
ACACTIVITY AC WITH (INDEX(ACVSET1))
WHERE
ACT.OBJ_ID = AP.ATN_OBJ_ID AND
ACT.ACTIVITY = AC.ACTIVITY AND
ACT.ACCT_CATEGORY != 'CAPEX'
```

Thankyou!

Comment: (?) possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14878164/give-the-db2-a-hint-which-index-to-use that previous question refers you to "selectivity" and/or a reminder to have current/relevant stats

Comment: Index (or any other) hints are not standard SQL. Besides, telling the database how to do its job is rarely a good idea.

Comment: Remove the clauses, the DB2 optimizer should be smart enough to choose the index by its own if its useful. And start to use an explicit `JOIN` operator instead of the outdated implicit joins in the `where` clause

Answer (score -1):

Well, choosing an index or other ways of accessing the data should be the task of the database system, not the user. Data distribution, database technology, available resources like memory and disk might change, still your query should work in an optimial way due to the database system figuring out an optimal access plan.

If you still believe this should be influenced, then [DB2 offers several features to do so](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc-gentopic3.html): Database configuration parameters or better session-specific environment settings, optimization profiles, different ways of maintaining statistics, ...