# DB2 join optimization with subqueries (NLJOIN vs HSJOIN)

Tags: sql, join, db2, query-optimization, db2-luw

I'm trying to fix the performance of a query I use to count data. On one of the queries the optimizer of DB2 LUW chooses to do a nested loop join instead of an hash join.

**The problematic query** (Resulting in NLJOIN)

```
with
  source1 as (select COALESCE(CAST("LOGICAL_KEY" AS CHARACTER VARYING(4000)), ']#[') as LOGICAL_KEY from "SAMPLE"."SOURCE1"),
  source2 as (select COALESCE(CAST("LOGICAL_KEY" AS CHARACTER VARYING(4000)), ']#[') as LOGICAL_KEY from "SAMPLE"."SOURCE2")
select count(*) from (
  SELECT
    "a"."LOGICAL_KEY",
    "b"."LOGICAL_KEY"
  FROM
   source1 "a",
   source2 "b"
 WHERE
   "a"."LOGICAL_KEY" =
   "b"."LOGICAL_KEY"
);
```

However when I create a table of the subqueries first, the optimizer performs an hash join.

**The optimized Query** (Resulting in HSJOIN)

```
CREATE TABLE "SAMPLE"."TMP_SOURCE1" ("LOGICAL_KEY" VARCHAR(4000 BYTE));
CREATE TABLE "SAMPLE"."TMP_SOURCE2" ("LOGICAL_KEY" VARCHAR(4000 BYTE));

insert into "SAMPLE"."TMP_SOURCE1" select COALESCE(CAST("LOGICAL_KEY" AS CHARACTER VARYING(4000)), ']#[') LOGICAL_KEY from "SAMPLE"."SOURCE1";
insert into "SAMPLE"."TMP_SOURCE2" select COALESCE(CAST("LOGICAL_KEY" AS CHARACTER VARYING(4000)), ']#[') LOGICAL_KEY from "SAMPLE"."SOURCE2";

select count(*) from (
  SELECT
    "a"."LOGICAL_KEY",
    "b"."LOGICAL_KEY"
  FROM
    (select * from "SAMPLE"."TMP_SOURCE1") "a",
    (select * from "SAMPLE"."TMP_SOURCE2") "b"
  WHERE
    "a"."LOGICAL_KEY" =
    "b"."LOGICAL_KEY"
);
```

How come that DB2 chooses different paths for the same data? Is there any way to force the structure with a subquery to perform an hash join? Due to privilege restrictions I'm not able to create tables.

Comment: Given your permissions levels, this might not be a real answer to your question, but . . . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14136463/is-it-possible-to-replace-nl-join-with-hs-join-in-sql/14141420#comment19626050_14141420.

Comment: Creating a query optimization profile isn't really an option, however it is an interesting read.

Comment: Can you create session tables?

Comment: What is the data type of `LOGICAL_KEY`? Are there actually null values of it in both tables?

Comment: Session tables shouldn't be a problem... The data type of logical key could be varying, one of the main reasons there is a cast in there. This query is only used when one of the fields is nullable, so yes nulls are possible.

Comment: How can a column data type be "varying"? Can you post the table definitions?

Comment: Why do you consider the `NLJOIN` to be a problem vs the `HSJOIN`?  

The DB2 optimizer will build the best plan it can based on available information.  You don't provide DDL for your source tables, you don't provide an explain, etc.

Comment: The same query is used against a different number of tables, so the data type of the column isn't the same. However it is limited to types that can be concatted.The NLJOIN is a problem since we join the whole table and the NLJOIN takes a few minutes on only a set of 80.000 rows and an HSJOIN does it in 0.5 sec.

Answer (score 0):

What is the db2level in your setup ? If it is DB2 v9 or older, then one reason why optimizer did not even consider HSJOIN is that the problematic query contains join predicate on expression. In this case, optimization profile is not an option. Use of session tables is a good idea.

From DB2 v10, HSJOIN also works for join on expression. So, the optimizer starts considering it. But the final decision is still cost-based. The plan that is estimated to be cheaper wins.

References:

[v97 info](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc/doc/c0055216.html)

[v10 info](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc/doc/c0055216.html?lang=en)

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally you are not comparing apples with apples. In your first scenario building tables a and b is being done as part of the query and the optimiser includes this work as part of its' whole join strategy. Since it has to build the tables in memory an NLjoin scanning them is not too much extra work. In the second scenario the optimiser considers a join between two existing tables with an equivalence predicate and finds that HSjoin is the way to go.